# Disabling selectOneMenu with selectOneRadio using AJAX selectonemenu not returning any value selected when enabled

Tags: ajax, jsf

I have problem with JSF I want to be develop an interface that allows the user to disable the `SelectOneMenu` when the select the all options of the radio button and when they select the select one option the `SelectOneMenu` should be enabled this should be done via AJAX. This part is working but the problem is that when the `SelectOneMenu` is active and the user select one value in the dropdown the `value="#{tripsForm.rh_name}"` is not available in the backing bean or not binding to the field in backing bean which is `rh_name`. I wrapped the `SelectOneMenu` in a `panelGrid` but this does not seem to work also. the code for xhtml...and the method for disabling `SelectOneMenu`...

```html
     <h:selectOneRadio id="rhNameStatus" valueChangeListener="#{tripsForm.disableInput}" >
              <f:selectItem itemValue="false" itemLabel="Select One Right Holder" />
              <f:selectItem itemValue="true" itemLabel="Select All Right Holder"/> 
              <p:ajax event="click" update=":form1:rhpanellanding" />
     </h:selectOneRadio>

      <p:panelGrid id="rhpanellanding" columns="2" style="width: 50%">   
            <h:outputLabel  for="rh_namelanding" value="Right Holder Name"/>
              <p:selectOneMenu id="rh_namelanding" value="#{tripsForm.rh_name}" rendered="true"  effect="fold" editable="false" disabled="#{tripsForm.disabled}">
                 <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />
                 <f:selectItems value="#{backingBeanTripDA.rh_nameList()}" /> 
              </p:selectOneMenu>
      </p:panelGrid>
```

```java
 public void disableInput(ValueChangeEvent event){

      String  selectedVal=  event.getNewValue().toString();
      if("true".equalsIgnoreCase(selectedVal)){
        disabled=true;
      } else if("false".equalsIgnoreCase(selectedVal)){
        disabled=false;
      }

    }
                `
```